# Mongodb many to many relation issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I have a small issue here to dynamically retrieve documents and update them.
I have a many-to-many relation between 2 documents: House with an userid and my User collection.
What I want to do is: save an User document found with the idUser from the House document, to the House document

My house document looks like this:

House:

```
{ 
"id": 1
"idUser": 3
}
```

and my User document:

```
{
"id": 3
"name" : Test
"lastname": TEST
}
```

and I want the following result:

House:

```
{
"id":1
"idUser":3
"user": { "name": Test, "lastname": TEST }   // document fetched from the House's idUser
```

Here is an example of my code:

```
house.find().done(function(err,h){

    for(var i = 0 ; i < h.length ; i++){
        User.findOne({ id: h.idUser}).done(function(err,user){

        h[i].user = user;    // issue here is that the variable 'i' is not defined anymore     after it enters in the "done" function 
     }

    console.log(h);   

    }

});
```

Would be thankful to anyone who has a clue about it.
Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the async function call within your for-loop. This cannot work because, when the callback is is called the first time, the loop is done and `i` equals `h.length`.

You have to do it this way:

```
house.find().done( function( err, h ) {
    function processHouse( i, callback ) {
        if( i < h.length ) {
            console.log( "House: " + i );
            User.findOne({ id: h.idUser}).done( function( err, user ){
                h[i].user = user;    // issue here is that the variable 'i' is not defined anymore     after it enters in the "done" function 
                processHouse( i+1, callback );
            });
        } else {
            callback()
        }
    }
    processHouse( 0, function() {
        console.log( "Done!" );
    });
});
```

I would recommend you to study this [link](https://blog.jcoglan.com/2010/08/30/the-potentially-asynchronous-loop/).